# Проблема DataBinding - Error cannot find symbol

Tags: android, android-data-binding

Имею проблему с DataBindig, есть layout который надуваю во фрагменте

FragmentUserProfileEditMain:

```
class FragmentUserProfileEditMain : Fragment(), ViewStateUserProfileEditMain {
   lateinit var binding: FragmentUserProfileEditMainBinding
   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        }

        override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View {
             binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
                inflater, R.layout.fragment_user_profile_edit_main, container, false)
            return binding.getRoot()
        }
```

Gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
   .....
}
dependencies {
    def dagger_version = "2.18"
    def support_version = '1.0.0-beta01'
    def arch_version = '2.0.0-alpha1'
    ...
    //Google Arch
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:$arch_version"
    kapt "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:$arch_version"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$arch_version"
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$arch_version"
    kapt "androidx.databinding:databinding-compiler:3.3.2"

    implementation 'android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment:1.0.0-rc02'
    ......
    }
```

fragment_user_profile_edit_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <data>
        ...
    </data>
    <ScrollView

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                                           android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    ...
```

class FragmentUserProfileEditMainBinding нормально генерируется, но компилятор выдает следующую ошибку

```
D:\Android\cod\app\build\generated\source\kapt\debug\ru\test\data\DataBinderMapperImpl.java:18: error: cannot find symbol
import ru.ohmypeer.peers.databinding.FragmentUserProfileEditMainBindingImpl;
                                    ^
  symbol:   class FragmentUserProfileEditMainBindingImpl
  location: package ru.test.data.databinding
```

Я пробовал открывать закрывать Android studio. Clear/rebuild project, Invalidate cache/restart